# ¿Cómo puedo adherir ciertas columnas de una tabla?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo una duda, tengo una tabla en la cual están los **nombres de empleados** y **documento** en las primeras columnas de la tabla y en las columnas siguientes se aprecia la información respectiva para cada uno, lo que pasa es que tengo un **scrollbar horizontal** por lo que la tabla queda muy grande, pero sí me desplazo hacia la derecha para ver el resto de la información se pierden las columnas **nombre y documento** por lo que hace complicado leer la tabla, la duda que tengo es, ¿Hay posibilidad de dejar esas columnas adheridas y cuando se desplace con el **scroll** se desplacen esas columnas también? Sí alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradezco

Adjunto captura de la tabla:

[image: Imagen de la tabla]

Adjunto el código `html` de la tabla:

```
<div class='d-flex justify-content-center' id="contentTable">
            <table class='table table-stripped' style="width: 150%" border=1 id="table">
                    <thead class= 'thead-dark'>

                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

La tabla la lleno después de hacer una petición con `ajax`, la lleno con `jquery` así:

```
$("table thead").html("");
                    $("table tbody").html("");

                    var thead = "<tr>"
                        + "<th>#</th>"
                        + "<th>Documento</th>"
                        + "<th>Nombre</th>";

                    for(let i=0; i < response["dias"].length; i++){
                        thead += "<th>"+ response["dias"][i]["dia"] +"</th>";
                    }
                        + "</tr>";
                    thead += "<tr> <th colspan='3'></th>";
                    for(let i=0; i < response["dias"].length; i++){
                        thead += "<th>"+ response["dias"][i]["fecha"] +"</th>";
                    }
                        thead += "</tr>";
                    var tbody;
                    for (let i = 0; i < response["empleados"].length; i++) {
                        if(i%2 == 0){
                            tbody += "<tr class='table-active'>";
                        }else{
                            tbody += "<tr>";
                        }
                        tbody += "<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td>"
                        + "<td>"+response["empleados"][i]["documento"]+"</td>"
                        + "<td>"+response["empleados"][i]["nombres"]+ " " +response["empleados"][i]["apellidos"]+"</td>";
                        index = 0
                        for(let j = 0; j < response["dias"].length; j++){
                            if(response["datos"][i] != null  && typeof response["datos"][i][index] != "undefined"){
                                if(response["datos"][i][index]["dia"] == response["dias"][j]["fecha"]){
                                    var color = "";
                                    if(response["datos"][i][index]["siglas"] == "TC"){
                                        color = "#B7E1CD";
                                    }else if(response["datos"][i][index]["siglas"] == "VAC"){
                                        color = "#E69138";
                                    }else if(response["datos"][i][index]["siglas"] == "DP"){
                                        color = "#E06666";
                                    }else if(response["datos"][i][index]["siglas"] == "DC"){
                                        color = "#FFE599";
                                    }else if(response["datos"][i][index]["siglas"] == "MT"){
                                        color = "#F4C7C3";
                                    }else if(response["datos"][i][index]["siglas"] == "INC"){
                                        color = "#A41785";
                                    }else if(response["datos"][i][index]["siglas"] == "RT"){
                                        color = "#00B0F0";
                                    }else if(response["datos"][i][index]["siglas"] == "HE"){
                                        color = "#8064A2";
                                    }else if(response["datos"][i][index]["siglas"] == "SUSP"){
                                        color = "#C00000";
                                    }else if(response["datos"][i][index]["siglas"] == "NE"){
                                        color = "#C23B00";
                                    }

                                    if(color != null){
                                        tbody += "<td style='background-color: "+ color +"'>"+response["datos"][i][index]["siglas"]+"</td>";
                                    }else{
                                        tbody += "<td>"+response["datos"][i][index]["siglas"]+"</td>";
                                    }
                                    index++;
                                }else{
                                    tbody += "<td> </td>";
                                }
                            }else{
                                tbody += "<td> </td>";
                            }
                        }
                        tbody += "</tr>";
                    }
                    $("table thead").append(thead);
                    $("table tbody").append(tbody);
```

Comment: Te comparto, este link, es lo que necesitas realizar? 
https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/left_right_columns.html.

Comment: Sí, exactamente eso, voy a revisarlo, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estimado, te comento que existe un plugin que pinta tablas llamado DataTables el cual dentro de sus cualidades (de por si bien personalizables) existe una propiedad llamada "fixedColumns" expresado de la siguiente manera:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        scrollY:        "300px",
        scrollX:        true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging:         false,
        fixedColumns:   {
            leftColumns: 1,
            rightColumns: 1
        }
    } );
} );
```

```css
th,
td {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.dataTables_wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.6/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.6/css/fixedColumns.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<table id="example" class="stripe row-border order-column" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
      <th>Extn.</th>
      <th>E-mail</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger</td>
      <td>Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>5421</td>
      <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett</td>
      <td>Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
      <td>8422</td>
      <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton</td>
      <td>Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
      <td>1562</td>
      <td>a.cox@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

No olvidar que para inicializar estas propiedades debes ingresar las librerias del plugin citadas en [este enlance](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/left_right_columns.html), cualquier consulta no dudes en preguntar.

**EDIT**:
Estimado, si por casualidad estuvieses un poco complicado con el diseño intenta esto:

Debes asignar `position: absolute` a la columna que quieres dejar fija y `padding-left: 74.5px!important;` a la columna que sigue para que pueda verse.

```css
table {
  display: block;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.static {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
}

.first-col {
  padding-left: 94.5px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="static" scope="col">FIJAR</th>
      <th class="first-col" scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="static" scope="row">FIJAR</th>
      <td class="first-col">Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="static" scope="row">FIJAR</th>
      <td class="first-col">Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="static" scope="row">FIJAR</th>
      <td class="first-col">Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Código de respuesta en [este enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/131242/118752)

Comment: Sabes depronto por qué se da este error?
DataTables warning: table id=table - FixedColumns is not needed (no x-scrolling in DataTables enabled), so no action will be taken. Use 'FixedHeader' for column fixing when scrolling is not enabled

Comment: Ese error estimado da cuando no incluyes el CSS del complemento [Fixed Table Plugins](https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.0/css/fixedColumns.dataTables.min.css) y [librería FIxed Clomuns de DataTables](https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.0/css/fixedColumns.dataTables.min.css)

Comment: El problema es que sí lo implemento, me jode el diseño que ya tengo

Comment: @DaxTter77 esta es la mejor solución que tienes. DataTables funciona muy bien. No es dificil adaptar los estilos. Los demás plugins de tablas, al menos los que he probado yo, no funcionan 100% bien

Comment: Estimado, edité la respuesta con un código añadido en CSS, este lo debes adaptar a tus necesidades dado que no pude citar el tuyo, por falta de datos.

Comment: Es que el problema es que como yo hago el scroll en el div no en la tabla, entonces me complica las cosas, además tendrías que hacer esos mismo cambios en todas las tablas que tengo y es muy complicado, pues voy a ver que puedo hacer, sino que se me complica

Comment: Estimado, creo que la unica solución que tienes sería migrar a alguna de estas 2 soluciones, creo que es mas complicado adaptar cada div a un scroll que una tabla a un scroll, tendrías que crear clases distintas en CSS para cada una de las tablas según el ancho de tu cabecera. Lo mas recomendable es seguir a @Emeeus y cambiar los estilos en un DataTables, ya que este te requerirá solo 1 trabajo "tedioso" 1 sola vez.

Comment: Vale, intentaré ver como acomodo eso de tal manera que quede bien, muchas gracias a ambos

Comment: Hice lo que pude hasta que ya, muchas gracias, hice fue lo del dataTable