# ¿Como puedo fijar la primera columna de una tabla HTML?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Básicamente necesito "fijar" la primera columna de una tabla para que al desplazarse hacia la derecha se siga mostrando, debido a que son muchas columnas y asi seria mas facil de entender la información. Intente haciendo algo similar a lo de este [ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/130712/columna-fija-tabla-html-con-bootstrap-3), pero aunque se sobrepone parecido a lo que necesito, me surgen 2 problemas, el primero es que el ancho de la columna no es uniforme, sino que se ajusta al texto que contiene cada celda y segundo la columna (META), que está después de la que estoy fijando no se ve, ya que queda por debajo de la columna "fijada". ¿Como puedo lograr lo que necesito?

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0rem;
  color: #858796;
  display: block;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.table th,
.table td {
  padding: 0.75rem;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #e3e6f0;
}

.table-bordered {
  border: 1px solid #e3e6f0;
}

.static {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
}

.first-col {
  padding-left: 74.5px!important;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered collaptable">
    <thead>
      <tr style="color:#555;font-size: 12px;" class="text-center">
        <th scope="col" colspan="5" class="align-middle text-center">5 GALONES (U)</th>
        <th scope="col" colspan="4" class="align-middle text-center">5 GALONES ($)</th>
        <th scope="col" colspan="4" class="align-middle text-center">NO RETORNABLE</th>
        <th scope="col" colspan="4" class="align-middle text-center">TOTAL</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<tr>
<td class="static"><strong>SUPERVISOR</strong></td>
<td class="first-col"><strong>META</strong></td>
<td><strong>VENTA</strong></td>
<td><strong>PY</strong></td>
<td><strong>ALC</strong></td>
<td><strong>META</strong></td>
<td><strong>VENTA</strong></td>
<td><strong>PY</strong></td>
<td><strong>ALC</strong></td>
<td><strong>META</strong></td>
<td><strong>VENTA</strong></td>
<td><strong>PY</strong></td>
<td><strong>ALC</strong></td>
<td><strong>META</strong></td>
<td><strong>VENTA</strong></td>
<td><strong>PY</strong></td>
<td><strong>ALC</strong></td></tr>
<tr>
<td class="static">NOMBRE</td>
<td class="first-col">2,700</td>
<td>651</td>
<td>2,116</td>
<td>78.4%</td>
<td>$3,306</td>
<td>$791</td>
<td>$2,572</td>
<td>77.8%</td>
<td>$200</td>
<td>$204</td>
<td>$662</td>
<td>330.8%</td>
<td>$3,506</td>
<td>$995</td>
<td>$3,234</td>
<td>92.2%</td></tr>
<tr>
<td class="static">OTRO NOMBRE</td>
<td class="first-col">2,700</td>
<td>651</td>
<td>2,116</td>
<td>78.4%</td>
<td>$3,306</td>
<td>$791</td>
<td>$2,572</td>
<td>77.8%</td>
<td>$200</td>
<td>$204</td>
<td>$662</td>
<td>330.8%</td>
<td>$3,506</td>
<td>$995</td>
<td>$3,234</td>
<td>92.2%</td></tr>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Al final de varias búsquedas en SO, encontre esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55673873/sticky-table-header-with-two-header-rows) la cual me ayudo junto con las otras respuestas de esta pregunta. Tal como me comentaron utilice la propiedad `sticky` en mi `CSS`, pero eso me llevó a otro problema, ya que tengo 2 encabezados de la tabla y con `sticky` solo uno de ellos se quedaba fijo, logre solucionarlo con `jQuery` tal como lo indicaba en la respuesta citada y al final logré el resultado esperado, quizá a alguien le resulte útil.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
        var firstheight = $('.first').height();
        $("thead tr.second th, thead tr.second td").css("top", firstheight)
    });
```

```css
.tablenm {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

thead th {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* for Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 1px solid #e3e6f0;
}

thead tr:first-child {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

tbody th {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* for Safari */
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  background: #FFF;
}

tbody tr {
  left: 0;
  top:0;
  z-index: 3;
}

table tbody:nth-of-type(1) tr:nth-of-type(1) td {
                border-top: none !important;
            }
            table thead th {
                border-top: none !important;
                border-bottom: none !important;
                box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #e3e6f0,
                            inset 0 -1px 0 #e3e6f0;
                padding: 2px 0;
            }
            table thead th {
                background-clip: padding-box
            }

td,
th {
  padding: 0em;
}

   thead tr.first th, thead tr.first td {
       position: sticky;
       position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
       top: 0;
       background: #FFFFFF;
   }

   thead tr.second th, thead tr.second td {
       position: sticky;
       position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
       background: #FFFFFF;
   }

.tablenm th,
.tablenm td {
  padding: 0.25rem;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #e3e6f0;
}

.tablenm thead th {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e3e6f0;
}

.tablenm tbody + tbody {
  border-top: 2px solid #e3e6f0;
}

.tablenm-sm th,
.tablenm-sm td {
  padding: 0.3rem;
}

.tablenm-bordered {
  border: 1px solid #e3e6f0;
}

.tablenm-bordered th,
.tablenm-bordered td {
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e6f0;
  border-right: 1px solid #e3e6f0;
}

.tablenm-bordered thead th,
.tablenm-bordered thead td {
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height: 525px;">
<table class="tablenm tablenm-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr class="text-center first" style=" font-size: 12px;color: #555;">
        <th colspan="5" ><strong>5 GALONES (U)</strong></th>
        <th colspan="4" ><strong>5 GALONES ($)</strong></th>
        <th colspan="4" ><strong>NO RETORNABLE</strong></th>
        <th colspan="4" ><strong>TOTAL</strong></th>
      </tr>
     <tr class="align-middle text-center second" style=" font-size: 12px;color: #555;">
      <th><strong>SUPERVISOR</strong></th>
      <th><strong>META</strong></th>
      <th><strong>VENTA</strong></th>
      <th><strong>PY</strong></th>
      <th><strong>ALC</strong></th>
      <th><strong>META</strong></th>
      <th><strong>VENTA</strong></th>
      <th><strong>PY</strong></th>
      <th><strong>ALC</strong></th>
      <th><strong>META</strong></th>
      <th><strong>VENTA</strong></th>
      <th><strong>PY</strong></th>
      <th><strong>ALC</strong></th>
      <th><strong>META</strong></th>
      <th><strong>VENTA</strong></th>
      <th><strong>PY</strong></th>
      <th><strong>ALC</strong></th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<tr>
<th>NOMBRE 1</th>
<td>2,700</td>
<td>651</td>
<td>2,116</td>
<td>78.4%</td>
<td>$3,306</td>
<td>$791</td>
<td>$2,572</td>
<td>77.8%</td>
<td>$200</td>
<td>$204</td>
<td>$662</td>
<td>330.8%</td>
<td>$3,506</td>
<td>$995</td>
<td>$3,234</td>
<td>92.2%</td></tr>
<tr>
<th>NOMBRE 2</th>
<td>2,700</td>
<td>651</td>
<td>2,116</td>
<td>78.4%</td>
<td>$3,306</td>
<td>$791</td>
<td>$2,572</td>
<td>77.8%</td>
<td>$200</td>
<td>$204</td>
<td>$662</td>
<td>330.8%</td>
<td>$3,506</td>
<td>$995</td>
<td>$3,234</td>
<td>92.2%</td></tr>
<tr>
<th>NOMBRE 3</th>
<td>2,700</td>
<td>651</td>
<td>2,116</td>
<td>78.4%</td>
<td>$3,306</td>
<td>$791</td>
<td>$2,572</td>
<td>77.8%</td>
<td>$200</td>
<td>$204</td>
<td>$662</td>
<td>330.8%</td>
<td>$3,506</td>
<td>$995</td>
<td>$3,234</td>
<td>92.2%</td></tr><tr>
<th>NOMBRE 4</th>
<td>2,700</td>
<td>651</td>
<td>2,116</td>
<td>78.4%</td>
<td>$3,306</td>
<td>$791</td>
<td>$2,572</td>
<td>77.8%</td>
<td>$200</td>
<td>$204</td>
<td>$662</td>
<td>330.8%</td>
<td>$3,506</td>
<td>$995</td>
<td>$3,234</td>
<td>92.2%</td></tr>
<tr>
<th>NOMBRE 5</th>
<td>2,700</td>
<td>651</td>
<td>2,116</td>
<td>78.4%</td>
<td>$3,306</td>
<td>$791</td>
<td>$2,572</td>
<td>77.8%</td>
<td>$200</td>
<td>$204</td>
<td>$662</td>
<td>330.8%</td>
<td>$3,506</td>
<td>$995</td>
<td>$3,234</td>
<td>92.2%</td></tr>
<tr>
<th>NOMBRE 6</th>
<td>2,700</td>
<td>651</td>
<td>2,116</td>
<td>78.4%</td>
<td>$3,306</td>
<td>$791</td>
<td>$2,572</td>
<td>77.8%</td>
<td>$200</td>
<td>$204</td>
<td>$662</td>
<td>330.8%</td>
<td>$3,506</td>
<td>$995</td>
<td>$3,234</td>
<td>92.2%</td></tr>
<tr>
<th>NOMBRE 7</th>
<td>2,700</td>
<td>651</td>
<td>2,116</td>
<td>78.4%</td>
<td>$3,306</td>
<td>$791</td>
<td>$2,572</td>
<td>77.8%</td>
<td>$200</td>
<td>$204</td>
<td>$662</td>
<td>330.8%</td>
<td>$3,506</td>
<td>$995</td>
<td>$3,234</td>
<td>92.2%</td></tr>
<tr>
<th>NOMBRE 8</th>
<td>2,700</td>
<td>651</td>
<td>2,116</td>
<td>78.4%</td>
<td>$3,306</td>
<td>$791</td>
<td>$2,572</td>
<td>77.8%</td>
<td>$200</td>
<td>$204</td>
<td>$662</td>
<td>330.8%</td>
<td>$3,506</td>
<td>$995</td>
<td>$3,234</td>
<td>92.2%</td></tr>
<tr>
<th>NOMBRE 9</th>
<td>2,700</td>
<td>651</td>
<td>2,116</td>
<td>78.4%</td>
<td>$3,306</td>
<td>$791</td>
<td>$2,572</td>
<td>77.8%</td>
<td>$200</td>
<td>$204</td>
<td>$662</td>
<td>330.8%</td>
<td>$3,506</td>
<td>$995</td>
<td>$3,234</td>
<td>92.2%</td></tr>
<tr>
<th>NOMBRE 10</th>
<td>2,700</td>
<td>651</td>
<td>2,116</td>
<td>78.4%</td>
<td>$3,306</td>
<td>$791</td>
<td>$2,572</td>
<td>77.8%</td>
<td>$200</td>
<td>$204</td>
<td>$662</td>
<td>330.8%</td>
<td>$3,506</td>
<td>$995</td>
<td>$3,234</td>
<td>92.2%</td></tr>
<tr>
<th>NOMBRE 11</th>
<td>2,700</td>
<td>651</td>
<td>2,116</td>
<td>78.4%</td>
<td>$3,306</td>
<td>$791</td>
<td>$2,572</td>
<td>77.8%</td>
<td>$200</td>
<td>$204</td>
<td>$662</td>
<td>330.8%</td>
<td>$3,506</td>
<td>$995</td>
<td>$3,234</td>
<td>92.2%</td></tr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que podes intentar es ponerle un ancho fijo a la columna fija para solucionar el primer problema. Debes garantizar que cualquier celda de esta columna entre dentro del ancho que setees.

```
.static {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  width: 110px; 
}
```

Después para el segundo problema deberías tener en cuenta cual es el ancho de la columna fija dado que la columna fija tiene `position: absolute`

```
.first-col {
  padding-left: 150px!important; // un valor mayor a al ancho de la columna fija
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado!

Comment: Lo pruebo y te comento.

Answer (score 1):

Hace tiempo hice una tabla parecida, y guarde el script, te lo comparto, la magia la hace colocarle a la columna que quieres que sea fija con `position: sticky;`

```css
.table-scroll {
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 350px;
}
.table-scroll table {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1280px;
  margin: auto;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
.table-wrap {
  position: relative;
}
.table-scroll th,
.table-scroll td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.table-scroll thead th {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.table-scroll tfoot,
.table-scroll tfoot th,
.table-scroll tfoot td {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #666;
  color: #fff;
  z-index:4;
}

th:first-child {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #ccc;
}
thead th:first-child,
tfoot th:first-child {
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<div id="table-scroll" class="table-scroll">
  <table id="main-table" class="main-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Header 1</th>
        <th scope="col">Header 2</th>
        <th scope="col">Header 3 with longer content</th>
        <th scope="col">Header 4 text</th>
        <th scope="col">Header 5</th>
        <th scope="col">Header 6</th>
        <th scope="col">Header 7</th>
        <th scope="col">Header 8</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>First top Column</th>
        <td>Cell content<br>
          test </td>
        <td><a href="#">Cell content longer</a></td>
        <td>Cell content with more content and more content Cell </td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td><a href="#">Cell content longer</a></td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Column<br>
          last</th>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content longer</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>Footer 1</th>
        <td>Footer 2</td>
        <td>Footer 3</td>
        <td>Footer 4</td>
        <td>Footer 5</td>
        <td>Footer 6</td>
        <td>Footer 7</td>
        <td>Footer 8</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Si no es demasiado pedir, podrías aplicarlo al ejemplo que puse por favor, es que no he comprendido muy bien cómo debería aplicarse. Gracias desde ya.

Comment: Bro es simplemente cambiar texto